# Is there a way of changing custom values for each client without building a whole new apk?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I don't really know how to explain this, but let's say I had a web app, and I wanted to change things like some settings of some sort after a deploy the web app to the client, normally I would have to go to a .settings file or a .config file and change it from there after I deploy it. Is there any way I can do that on Android as well?
like for example, let's say each client has a custom url, and I have to access it from the android app, how can I change that url, without building a whole new apk, but only changing a .settings file or a .config file?
Does anyone know if that's possible? Thanks!

Edit: Also keep in mind that this is not an app that should go public on the play store, but it's instead meant to be a business to business application.

Comment: You can use either your server and set values on it, send them to Android, or you can use [Firebase remote config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/?gclid=CjwKCAiAt9z-BRBCEiwA_bWv-NHOahFAYP2bVLK1B1QP2Wd1lDgoZK4FJqYhwXuLQpwAbA5GDBN3cxoCuJcQAvD_BwE)

Comment: @Vucko Hi! Thanks for the comment, I just took a look at remote config, it looks pretty good, but can you actually make changes to individual clients? From the little I've seen it doesn't look like so but I could be completely wrong. Thank you!

Comment: We're doing exactly that in our project. You can create a custom JSON that you can store there. You can keep different configurations for distinct clients, just save them under a unique key for each.

Comment: @Vucko ok thank you I kinda get it (i'm pretty new to this lol sorry), is there an article somewhere or some kind of resaurce where I can learn more about this  specifically? Thank you again :)

Comment: Not sure, other than the official docs for Remote config. But you can save anything in there, you can have a list of objects where each one is a configuration for a particular client. There's a myriad of ways you can solve it

Comment: @Vucko Hi and thanks !   I was also wondering if I can use this even if I never used Firebase before? I read online that I needed some kind of authentication and realtime database for each user record? Is that true? I've never used firebase before I don't really know how it works

Comment: Firebase encompasses a large variety of features (analytics, crashlytics, and so on), Remote config being only 1 of it's many features. You do need to create a google account and register a new Firebase app, but it's all free and easily doable even if you've never done it. Just follow the docs.